# How to set preferred PDF viewer for texdoc in TeXLive 2010 pretest.

Tags: pdf, environments, texdoc, viewers

I had evince, installed TexLive 2010 pretest (ubuntu lucid linx, fresh install). texdoc was using evince. Then I installed kubuntu ontop, and texdoc switched to okular. Now I've installed acroread and texdoc is using it now.

I want to globally set it to use evince. How do I do that? (tried all the environmental variables mentioned in the man page and no luck so far)

Comment: Just to check, you tried setting `PDFVIEWER_texdoc`, right?

Comment: Muahaha =) PDFVIEWER_texdoc did the trick. I have used PDFVIEWER instead.

Comment: Oh, well okay! I'm surprised that `PDFVIEWER` didn't work for you, since if I'm reading the documentation right, it should be the second thing that `texdoc` checks after `PDFVIEWER_texdoc`. But anyway, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If it hasn't changed since TeXLive 2009, you can set

```
viewer_pdf=evince
```

in the configuration file. To find out which file to put that in, run

```
texdoc -f
```

and you will see some output like this:

```
texdoc 0.61
Configuration files are:
    absent      /home/username/texmf/texdoc/texdoc-bin.cnf
(*) absent      /home/username/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
    absent      /home/username/texmf/texdoc/texdoc-dist.cnf
    absent      /usr/local/share/texmf/texdoc/texdoc-bin.cnf
    absent      /usr/local/share/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
    active      /usr/share/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
(*) This is the recommended configuration file for your personal preferences.
```

Put the line in the filename marked by the `(*)`, creating it if necessary.

**EDIT:** To add to the above explanation: according to the documentation (and again, this is for TeXlive 2009), `texdoc` gets its configuration information from 5 sources.

1. Command-line options (irrelevant for this question, since there's no CL option to set the viewer app)
2. Environment variables ending with `_texdoc`. `PDFVIEWER_texdoc` is the one that controls the PDF viewer.
3. Other environment variables. For the PDF viewer app, these are

   - `PDFVIEWER`
   - `TEXDOCVIEW_pdf`
   - `TEXDOC_VIEWER_PDF`

   The documentation isn't clear on which order they're checked in but `PDFVIEWER` is the preferred alternative so I'd expect it to take precedence over the others.
4. Values from configuration files, read in the order given by `texdoc -f`
5. Hard-coded defaults (system-dependent)

Again, this is all explained in the documentation, which can be accessed by running

```
texdoc texdoc
```

Comment: (*) active /home/tdlk/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf

$ cat ~/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
viewer_pdf=evince

Still launches acroread..... =(

Comment: Weird... in that case I have no idea. I tried it out and it works for me.

Comment: Just makesure that PDFVIEWER and PDFVIEWER_texdoc are not set, then it works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I probably should have included the info about environment variables in the first place.

Comment: Oddly enough, the precedence of environement variables is: PDFVIEWER_texdoc, TEXDOCVIEW_pdf, TEXDOC_VIEWER_PDF, PDFVIEWER. The goal is to be consistent with the variables for html: BROWSER_texdoc, TEXDOCVIEW_html, TEXDOC_VIEWER_HTML, BROWSER where TEXDOC_VIEWER_HTML is more specific than BROWSER so clearly should have precedence. Anyway, using the configuration files is the prefered way to handle these settings.

Comment: Just for reference should others face this: I waned to use a desktop app, Skim, as the `texdoc` viewer under macOS. After trying various things in `~/Library/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf`, I found what worked was: `viewer_pdf=open -a Skim` (in other words, the usual way that one would open the app from the command line).

Answer (score 9):

When you get confused about what is set where, try `texdoc --debug=config`. It helps you find which environment variable you forgot, etc.

The variable `PDFVIEWER` should definitly work if no other variable is set for PDF.