# texdoc unable to open Adobe Reader

Tags: adobe, texdoc

I've just had to build my system up again since I got a new Mac.  I'm running into several problems I'm having problems sleuthing out.

One is about using `texdoc`.  When I try to run something like

> texdoc arara

I get the following error message

```
The application /Applications/Adobe Reader.app cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10827 "kLSNoExecutableErr: The executable is missing" UserInfo={_LSLine=3829, _LSFunction=_LSOpenStuffCallLocal}
texdoc error: Failed to execute: open -a /Applications/Adobe\ Reader.app "/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/support/arara/arara-manual.pdf"
```

As far as I can tell there is no `Adobe Reader` app anymore.  There is `Adobe Acrobat Reader DC`.  I'm not sure how to work around this.  I've tried going through the documentation for `texdoc` but I'm not seeing anything that clearly tells me how to configure the program with which to open documents.  Maybe I just don't understand the lingo.

What are suggestions for getting this working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set preferred PDF viewer for texdoc in TeXLive 2010 pretest.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260/how-to-set-preferred-pdf-viewer-for-texdoc-in-texlive-2010-pretest)

Comment: @user202729 Unfortunately not.

Comment: @user202729 I tried setting up as instructed and it seems to be ignored.  But also, I don't see where in the config files it's actually set up for Adobe Reader in the first place.

Comment: Then add to the question • what's the value of the environment variable? • what does the command show the path of the configuration files? • what's the content of the configuration files?

Comment: Maybe you can try `texdoc --debug arara` to see where the config comes from.

Comment: @user202729 I'm only briefly back on the grid this afternoon and won't be fully back until after the New Year.  I'm not sure what you're asking for "what's the value of the environment variable?"  What environment variable?  Which configuration files?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ This isn't a problem with `arara`'s documentation.  It's a problem with `texdoc`.  None of the documentation files can be opened using `texdoc`.

Comment: @user202729 I did a `grep` on the directory tree for `texmf` last week.  Nothing even turns up with `Adode Reader` on a `grep` search.  So, I can't really answer your questions until I can sit down at my real computer next week Monday (Jan 3).  But, on the surface, I have no clue what details you're looking for.  I know nothing about `texdoc` or how it's configured and what impinges upon it.

Comment: @user202729 Now that I'm not cramming to get my computer set up and pack things up to get away for the holidays, I was able to more careful peruse the linked answer.  It does work.  Thank you.